# Writing multiple nested for...in loops in Swift

Tags: swift, for-in-loop

Is there a tidier or better way to write the below nested for...in loops in Swift please? Or is using for...in even the correct way to populate my cards?

```
for cardNumber in 1...3 {
    for cardSymbolIdentifier in 1...3 {
        for cardColorIdentifier in 1...3 {
            for cardShadingIdentifier in 1...3 {
                let card = Card(cardNumber: cardNumber, cardSymbolIdentifier: cardSymbolIdentifier, cardColorIdentifier: cardColorIdentifier, cardShadingIdentifier: cardShadingIdentifier)
                deckOfCards.append(card)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It definitely does the job, but I can't find anything in the documentation about writing multiple nested loops.

Many thanks in advance,
Andy

Comment: This looks like a bad structure for your data at first glance.

Comment: Just curious: Is this for a [Set game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(card_game)) ?

Comment: @MartinR it probably [is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51200213/2907715). But that uses nested for loops too. To avoid them, all possible 4-element arrays using 1,2,3 should be generated (similar but not identical to [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/213593/49921))

Comment: @RakeshaShastri How so please? I'd love to know a better way to do it.

Comment: @ielyamani It is for Set - currently working through the iOS Stanford course. Thanks for both those links - I'll work through them now!

Comment: @ADB You need to tell us why you need your data like that.

Comment: In my opinion, your nested loops work perfect for your needs: They are straight forward, easy to read, easy to maintain, and there is no peformance issue at all to be thought of. Using more sophisticated functional stuff like flatMap etc. typically reduces the code size, but does not automatically improve the readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your for loops. They are excellent, well-written Swift. The only problem with your code is that it forces `deckOfCards` to be mutable (var), which *may* be undesirable. If it is, you could use a `map`, but I don't consider this particularly better Swift, just slightly different.

```
let d = (1...3).flatMap { number in
    (1...3).flatMap { symbol in
        (1...3).flatMap { color in
            (1...3).map { shading in
                Card.init(cardNumber: number,
                          cardSymbolIdentifier: symbol,
                          cardColorIdentifier: color,
                          cardShadingIdentifier: shading
                )}}}}
```

I would *probably* write it this second way, but only for stylistic reasons. Your for loops are absolutely fine.

---

Note @user28434's comment below. My [original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55574719/1) of this had a major bug (it returned the wrong type). I've been writing Swift since the day it was released. I teach Swift. I teach *functional programming* in Swift. And I screwed it up when writing it on the fly. I would never have made that mistake with a simple for loop. There's a major lesson in there.

Comment: It would be `[[[[Card]]]]` instead of flat `[Card]`. Some flattening required.

Comment: Lessons from boneheaded [mistakes](https://twitter.com/cocoaphony/status/1112145271566331904?s=20)

Answer (score 1):

If you Do that in a single loop, then it become arithmetically complex

```
for i in 0..<81 {
    deckOfCards.append(
        Card(cardNumber: i / 27, cardSymbolIdentifier: i/9 % 3, 
             cardColorIdentifier: i/3 % 3, cardShadingIdentifier: i % 3)
    )
}
```

or

```
let deckOfCards = (0..<81).map {

    Card(cardNumber: $0 / 27, cardSymbolIdentifier: $0/9 % 3, 
         cardColorIdentifier: $0/3 % 3, cardShadingIdentifier: $0 % 3)
}
```

In both example - indexing start with 0, so your class init function should **shift indexing little**
or
**add +1** in every parameter *before/after* passing

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no optimisation issues at all according to the need but you can make it a little more elegant or swifty (:p)

```
let values = [1,2,3]

values.forEach { (cardNumber) in
    values.forEach { (cardSymbolIdentifier) in
        values.forEach { (cardColorIdentifier) in
            values.forEach { (cardShadingIdentifier) in

                let card = Card(cardNumber: cardNumber, cardSymbolIdentifier: cardSymbolIdentifier, cardColorIdentifier: cardColorIdentifier, cardShadingIdentifier: cardShadingIdentifier)
                deckOfCards.append(card)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I disagree that `forEach` is more Swifty. `for...in` is a much more powerful, consistent, and flexible construct in Swift. At times, members of the core team have even suggested removing `forEach` because it has misleading behaviors and is redundant. The main reason for it is to provide symmetry with `filter` and `map` (and it can be useful there), but it should not be used to replace simple `for...in` loops IMO.

Comment: Why not go one step further and make it functional, by dropping mutation via `.append` and replacing `.forEach` with `.flatMap` (except in innermost iteration, where `.map` should be used and where you return your `Card` directly)?